# Generics & Reflection - GenericArguments[0] violates the constraint of type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, factory-pattern

I've been pulling my hair out for awhile on this one, essentially I'm trying to implement a generic repository factory, which is called as follows:

```
var resposFactory = new RepositoryFactory<IRepository<Document>>();
```

The repository factory looks like the following:

```
public class RepositoryFactory<T> : IRepositoryFactory<T>
{
    public T GetRepository(Guid listGuid,
        IEnumerable<FieldToEntityPropertyMapper> fieldMappings)
    {
        Assembly callingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        Type[] typesInThisAssembly = callingAssembly.GetTypes();

        Type genericBase = typeof (T).GetGenericTypeDefinition();

        Type tempType = (
            from type in typesInThisAssembly
            from intface in type.GetInterfaces()
            where intface.IsGenericType
            where intface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericBase 
            where type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
            select type)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (tempType != null)
        {
            Type newType = tempType.MakeGenericType(typeof(T));

            ConstructorInfo[] c = newType.GetConstructors();

            return (T)c[0].Invoke(new object[] { listGuid, fieldMappings });
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to call the GetRespository function the following line fails

```
Type newType = tempType.MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
```

The error I get is :

> ArgumentException - GenericArguments[0], 'Framework.Repositories.IRepository`1[Apps.Documents.Entities.PerpetualDocument]', on 'Framework.Repositories.DocumentLibraryRepository`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'.

Any ideas on what's going wrong here?

EDIT:

The implementation of the repository is as follows:

```
public class DocumentLibraryRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
                                                where T : class, new()
{
   public DocumentLibraryRepository(Guid listGuid, IEnumerable<IFieldToEntityPropertyMapper> fieldMappings)
   {
        ...
   }

   ...
}
```

And the IRepository looks like:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        void Add(T entity);
        void Remove(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        T FindById(int entityId);
        IEnumerable<T> Find(string camlQuery);
        IEnumerable<T> All();
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing a return statement there? Did you paste a complete copy of that method?

Comment: Also, why are you checking for the presence of a parameterless constructor when clearly you intend to invoke a constructor with parameters? If you have a parameterless constructor, it's most likely going to be the 0th constructor returned by `GetConstructors`, in which case calling it *with* parameters will fail.

Comment: Yes sorry 'return default(T)' should be at the end.

Comment: In regards to the check for the parameterless constructor?  What you are saying is correct, I was just playing around to see if I was doing something wrong tbh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code tries to create an instance of `DocumentLibraryRepository<IRepository<Document>>` instead of `DocumentLibraryRepository<Document>`.

You want to use this code instead:

```
var genericArgument = typeof(T).GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
if (tempType != null && genericArgument != null)
{
    Type newType = tempType.MakeGenericType(genericArgument);
```

Comment: Sorry yes I should have added that: 
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        void Add(T entity);
        void Remove(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        T FindById(int entityId);
        IEnumerable<T> Find(string camlQuery);
        IEnumerable<T> All();
    }

Comment: @Bevan: OK. Please see my updated answer. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this exactly same error, but the problem and solution was different. **I had 4 Model classes, 1 base class, and only 3 of them inherited from the base, 4th did not.** Once the last class inherited the base class, the error disappeared.

Comment: I've done this twice today, and had to google for your answer both times.  ::sigh:: It's gonna be a long day.  Either way, this answer is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

This would suggest that perhaps you've used a `where` constraint on the generic type `DocumentLibraryRepository<T>` and that the type `PerpetualDocument` does not match that constraint

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer can help someone that have the same error.
My scenario is :

```
public class B
{
    public string Name;
}

public class A
{
    public EventHandler<B> TypedEvent;

    public void MyMethod(B item)
    {
        if (TypedEvent != null)
        {
            TypedEvent(null, item);
        }
    }
}

public class T
{
    public void Run()
    {
        A item = new A();
        item.TypedEvent += new EventHandler<B>(ItemEvent);
    }

    private void ItemEvent(object sender, B b)
    {
        b.Name = "Loaded";
    }
}
```

So at runtime when Run() method is loaded (not executed) I get an exception:

> GenericArguments[0] .... System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs]' Violates
>   the constraint of the type parameter 'TEventArgs' .. on method Run().

I don't know if it's a .NET bug, but in my case i SOLVED this problem changing the type of `TypedEvent` property in `A` class from typed `EventHandler<B>` to  `EventHandler`.
My scenario become:

```
public class B
{
    public string Name;
}

public class A
{
    public EventHandler TypedEvent;

    public void MyMethod(B item)
    {
        if (TypedEvent != null)
        {
            TypedEvent(item, null);
        }
    }
}

public class T
{
    public void Run()
    {
        A item = new A();
        item.TypedEvent += new EventHandler(ItemEvent);
    }

    private void ItemEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        B b = sender as B;
        b.Name = "Loaded";
    }
}
```

I hope that can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I have changed my generic type to abstract at the suggestion of Resharper, obviously it couldn't be instantiated and resulted in this error.

Removed abstract and the method.MakeGenericMethod(type) line works again.